# Why should a class or struct must have no user defined constructor or destructor to ensure ROMability for const in C++?

Tags: c++, constants

I was reading a reference on C++ and there I found out that in order to ensure ROMability for an object defined as const :
1.The class or struct must have no user-defined constructors 
2.There can be no base classes or member objects with user defined constructors or destructors.
I am taking this in reference to bitwise const and not mutable const.
In my views ,the first one holds because the constructor or destructor modifies the const data members. So, we refrain from using user defined constructor or destructor.
But I can't get a good explaination for the second point.

Comment: Define **ROMability**. It is not a standard term AFAIK.

Comment: You have to define what you mean by "ROMability"? Is it to put the _code_ in ROM, or to put a complete _object_ in ROM? If the latter, then the class can't contain any code that modifies the object (you can't modify ROM), but if it's only to store the code, and you create the objects in RAM then there is no such limits.

Comment: If an object is defined as const, it is a candidate to be placed in ROM , which is  often an important consideration in embedded systems programming. So I am asking in this reference that to ensure this why do these points hold.

Comment: The C++ standard does not define *where* an object will be stored it only specify's the behaviors expected from objects depending on *storage specification*. At best this will be specific to an implementation or a platform.

Comment: Simply making an object const won't assure this right?

Comment: @AlokSave: Yes I know this isn't a C++ standard but this is used by eckel in his book Thinking in C++ in the chapter dealing with constants.

Comment: @AlokSave: However, the C++ standard *does* define when objects are initialised and destroyed, and that does place restrictions on which objects could be placed in read-only memory.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: It does, but there is no guarantee where the object will be placed. At best the answer to this Q is still implementation and platform dependent. The dilemma and concern expressed by the OP of being worried about *where* the objects will be places by the implementation cannot be answered within the purview of the standard.

Comment: @AlokSave: I agree that the standard doesn't say anything about object placement; but it's quite clear (to me at least) that the question is about whether an object *could* be placed in ROM, given a toolchain that gives you enough control to do that. That *can* be answered (and has been, twice) in relation to the standard, to the extent that objects that need run-time initialisation or destruction can't be placed in read-only memory.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: It only answers what can't be placed read-only memory but does not guarantee what will be. Op expressed the concern which needs latter not the former.

Comment: @AlokSave: Yes; but the question is just asking for a clarification of a particular case where it can't be, not for a any kind of guarantee about when it can be. It's been answered, and this argument is getting tedious and off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constructor / destructs would modify the object, which goes against it being stored in ROM.

If the class contains objects or inherits a constructor, that still is code that must run to construct the object (members are stored together with their parent objects). Which is not possible to do at compile-time (when ROM objects are assembled).

Comment: The bit about constructors is not true: there are constructors that both can and are run at compile time.  In C++03 it happens ad-hoc by the compiler doing it (the compiler isn't prevented from doing it, and some compilers do it): in C++11 there are explicit ways to insist on it happening (in effect).  Having a constructor does not always block being stored in something equivalent to `ROM` in any fundamental way.

Answer (score 3):

As you say, the first point is necessary because objects with user-defined constructors are initialised at run-time (during the dynamic initialisation phase before running `main`, if they have a static lifetime), and so can't be placed in read-only memory since that initialisation must modify the object's memory.

The second point follows from the first - if a (non-static) member or base sub-object has a user-defined constructor, then that constructor must also be used to initialise the member or sub-object at runtime. Therefore, at least part of the object can't be stored in read-only memory; and so the object itself can't be.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the definition of `POD` in C++03.  `POD` means plain old data.  A `const` global instance of that could be placed in `ROM` by some compiler and platform.

C++11 adds new language features that can mapped to `ROM`able.  `constexpr` constructors and standard layout types, between them, may be a reasonable set of restrictions on what some compiler can put into `ROM`.  But this will depend on the compiler's support for `ROM`ing data.